# I have 2 tables in my document. I found out their variable numbers, but I don't know how to go the next table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

Here is my code.

```vb
Sub sWordTables(daSN2, daGL, daST, daSY, daBEY, daENY, daSUP)
    Dim daDB As DAO.Database
    Dim appWord As Object 'Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Object 'Word.Document
    Dim wdTable As Object 'Word.Table'
    Dim cname As String
    Dim cnum As String
    Dim gss As Integer
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim aVar As String
    Dim wdcount As Integer
    
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim IntHolder As Integer
    Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    strPath = "C:\Users\wpulk\Documents\"
    
    Set daDB = CurrentDb()
    Set rst = daDB.OpenRecordset("qry" & daST, dbOpenDynaset)
    Set WordDoc = appWord.Documents.Open(strPath & "MasterRecord.docx")
    wdcount = WordDoc.Tables.Count
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        With WordDoc
            cname = rst!CourseName
            cnum = rst!CourseNumber
            gss = rst!GradeScore
            incn = rst!IncrementNumber
            wdcount = wdcount + 1
            
            If wdcount = 3 Then
                .Variables.Add ("StudentName"), daST
                .Variables.Add ("Academic Advisor"), daSUP
                .Variables.Add ("School Year"), daSY
                .Variables.Add ("Grade Level"), daGL
                .Variables.Add ("Beginning Date"), daBEY
                .Variables.Add ("Ending Date"), daENY
                .Fields.Update
            End If
            If wdcount >= 4 Then
                MsgBox .Variables(6).Name
                
                If .Variables("Math").Value = cname Then
                    .Variables.Add ("Math" & incn & "a"), cnum
                    .Variables.Add ("Math" & incn & "b"), gss
                ElseIf .Variables("English").Value = cname Then
                    .Variables.Add ("Eng" & incn & "a"), cnum
                    .Variables.Add ("Eng" & incn & "b"), gss
                ElseIf .Variables("Word Building").Value = cname Then
                    .Variables.Add ("WB" & incn & "a"), cnum
                    .Variables.Add ("WB" & incn & "b"), gss
                ElseIf .Variables("Lierature").Value = cname Then
                    .Variables.Add ("Lit" & incn & "a"), cnum
                    .Variables.Add ("Lit" & incn & "b"), gss
                ElseIf .Variables("Science").Value = cname Then
                    .Variables.Add ("Science" & incn & "a"), cnum
                    .Variables.Add ("Science" & incn & "b"), gss
                ElseIf .Variables("Social Studies").Value = cname Then
                    .Variables.Add ("SocS" & incn & "a"), cnum
                    .Variables.Add ("SocS" & incn & "b"), gss
                ElseIf .Variables("Bible").Value = cname Then
                    .Variables.Add ("Bible" & incn & "a"), cnum
                    .Variables.Add ("Bible" & incn & "b"), gss
                ElseIf .Variables("Florida History").Value = cname Then
                    .Variables.Add ("oth" & incn & "a"), cnum
                    .Variables.Add ("oth" & incn & "b"), gss
                    .Fields.Update
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Loop
    appWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs strPath & "MasterRecord" & daST & ".docx"
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set appWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

With other's help I was able to fix my first problem, but I have another problem where my document has 2 tables, and I know how to get the variable number of the first table, but I don't know how to get the second table. The first table has only 1 row and 6 columns, and I was able to process that one correctly, but when the code was going to what I thought was the second table, it did not. it was still at the first table.  I don't know what is the right code to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why you are initializing `wdcount` with the number of tables and also why it is called `wdcount`. You are not counting words, you are counting tables. Usually you start counting at 1 or maybe 0.

You could also count backwards. Then starting with the number of tables would be appropriate. But then the counter would have to be decreased at each iteration.

Here is what I suggest:

```vb
...
Dim tableIndex As Integer  '<=======
...
tableIndex = 1  '<=======
Do While Not rst.EOF
    With WordDoc
        cname = rst!CourseName
        cnum = rst!CourseNumber
        gss = rst!GradeScore
        incn = rst!IncrementNumber
        '===> wdcount = wdcount + 1 <==== removed!

        If tableIndex = 1 Then  '<=======
            .Variables.Add ("StudentName"), daST
            .Variables.Add ("Academic Advisor"), daSUP
            .Variables.Add ("School Year"), daSY
            .Variables.Add ("Grade Level"), daGL
            .Variables.Add ("Beginning Date"), daBEY
            .Variables.Add ("Ending Date"), daENY
           .Fields.Update
        End If
        If tableIndex >= 2 Then  '<=======
            MsgBox .Variables(6).Name
    
            If .Variables("Math").Value = cname Then
                .Variables.Add ("Math" & incn & "a"), cnum
                .Variables.Add ("Math" & incn & "b"), gss
                ...
            ...
            End If
        End If
    End With
    tableIndex = tableIndex + 1  '<======= ADDED!
Loop
...
```

I also suspect the conditions like `If .Variables("Math").Value = cname Then` to be wrong. Shouldn't you be testing the course name from the database like this:

```vb
Select Case cname
    Case "Math"
        .Variables.Add ("Math" & incn & "a"), cnum
        .Variables.Add ("Math" & incn & "b"), gss
    Case "English"
        .Variables.Add ("Eng" & incn & "a"), cnum
        .Variables.Add ("Eng" & incn & "b"), gss
    Case "Word Building"
        .Variables.Add ("WB" & incn & "a"), cnum
        .Variables.Add ("WB" & incn & "b"), gss
    Case "Lierature"   ' <==== Shoudn't this be "Literature"?
        .Variables.Add ("Lit" & incn & "a"), cnum
        .Variables.Add ("Lit" & incn & "b"), gss
    Case "Science"
        .Variables.Add ("Science" & incn & "a"), cnum
        .Variables.Add ("Science" & incn & "b"), gss
    Case "Social Studies"
        .Variables.Add ("SocS" & incn & "a"), cnum
        .Variables.Add ("SocS" & incn & "b"), gss
    Case "Bible"
        .Variables.Add ("Bible" & incn & "a"), cnum
        .Variables.Add ("Bible" & incn & "b"), gss
    Case "Florida History"
        .Variables.Add ("oth" & incn & "a"), cnum
        .Variables.Add ("oth" & incn & "b"), gss
End Select
.Fields.Update   ' <===== maybe this should be after `Loop`?
```

Or simplified:

```vb
Dim prefix As String
Select Case cname
    Case "Math"
        prefix = "Math"
    Case "English"
        prefix = "Eng"
    Case "Word Building"
        prefix = "WB"
    Case "Lierature"   ' <==== Shoudn't this be "Literature"?
        prefix = "Lit"
    Case "Science"
        prefix = "Science"
    Case "Social Studies"
        prefix = "SocS"
    Case "Bible"
        prefix = "Bible"
    Case "Florida History"
        prefix = "oth"
End Select
.Variables.Add (prefix & incn & "a"), cnum
.Variables.Add (prefix & incn & "b"), gss
```

Or even more simplified. First we take `cname` as a prefix and assign a corrected version if the prefix differs from `cname`:

```vb
Dim prefix As String
prefix = cname
Select Case cname
    Case "English"
        prefix = "Eng"
    Case "Word Building"
        prefix = "WB"
    Case "Lierature"   ' <==== Shoudn't this be "Literature"?
        prefix = "Lit"
    Case "Social Studies"
        prefix = "SocS"
    Case "Florida History"
        prefix = "oth"
End Select
.Variables.Add (prefix & incn & "a"), cnum
.Variables.Add (prefix & incn & "b"), gss
```

---

You are also not moving to the next record. The end of the loop should look like this:

```vb
        ...
    End With
    tableIndex = tableIndex + 1
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
WordDoc.Fields.Update
appWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs strPath & "MasterRecord" & daST & ".docx"
...
```

Comment: I changed  my code from the If to Case, But as you can see I am not getting to the second table. I only thought I was, but the MSgBox shows I was still in the first table. Just changing from wdcount to tableindex does not change that.

Comment: The statement `tableIndex = tableIndex + 1 ` definitely changes from table 1 to table 2 and then 3, 4, ...   [Debug your code](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code).

Comment: Ok that works.  But now, what is happening is that the query is not reading down and it keeps  reading the same  data.  I thought that my do loop was correct for a query. is that the problem?

Comment: Add a `rst.MoveNext` before the `Loop` line to move to the next record.